# Shuffle a 2D string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, shuffle

I'm doing a C++ program, in which I want to shuffle an array (or part of an array). Here is the array:

```
        string colorTheme[8][8] = {
            {"blue", "blue", "green", "green", "violet", "violet", "teal", "teal"},
            {"beige", "beige", "red", "red", "indigo", "indigo", "pink", "pink"},
            {"cyan", "cyan", "yellow", "yellow", "orange", "orange", "azure", "azure"},
            {"purple", "purple", "lime", "lime", "tangerine", "tangerine", "fuschia", "fuschia"},
            {"brown", "brown", "gray", "gray", "black", "black", "white", "white"},
            {"olive", "olive", "crimson", "crimson", "silver", "silver", "gold", "gold"},
            {"maroon", "maroon", "coral", "coral", "plum", "plum", "ivory", "ivory"},
            {"aqua", "aqua", "jade", "jade", "amber", "amber", "ruby", "ruby"}
        };
```

If I wanted to shuffle the first *n* rows and *n* columns, how would I do it? Ideally, I would run

```
shuffle(n);
```

because colorTheme is in the same class as `shuffle()`.

Comment: You cannot shuffle the array because it is `const`.

Comment: *If I wanted to shuffle the first n rows and n columns,* -- Given that input, what exactly do you mean by "shuffle the first n rows and n columns"?  Let's say you want to shuffle the first row -- isn't that going to shuffle the entire row, regardless of the column?

Comment: @MikeCAT I didn't specify this (my mistake), but I had a copy of the array with the same values. For now, I'll remove `const` from the declaration.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The array is a square of 8 strings by 8 strings. If I wanted to take a square of the first, say, four strings by four strings, and shuffle them, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: A hard-example of what a subN by subN shuffle of an N by N array would look like before and after is pretty-much mandatory for this ask. Specifically, it answers the inquisition of whether **all** cells in the subN by subN partition are viable to swap with all *other* cells in the same partition (as opposed to row-only or column-only). It makes a difference, as it significantly alters the possible algorithms to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to tackle this problem is to convert the 2D array into 1D, as shuffling a 1D array is a lot simpler. Under the covers, create an `int` array shuffler; fill an int array with values from 0 - n^2 and shuffle them using something like `rand`. From there, use the values in the `int` array as new positions for your string array. Once you have shuffled your string array, convert it back into a 1D array. Here is a simple c++ source file I created (feel free to use).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void shufflePos(int n, int arr[]);

void printArray(int *a, int length) {
    cout << "[ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
        cout << a[i];
        if (i != length - 1) {
            cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    cout << " ]\n";
}

void shufflePos(int n, int arr[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    } 
    // shuffle positions
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < (n - 2); i++) {
        /*if(arr[i] != i) // i has already been swapped
            continue;
        */
        int tmp = arr[i];
//        cout << "i = " << i << ", n - i = " << (n - i) << ", ";
        int random = rand();
//        cout << "random = " << random << ", ";
        int nextPos = i + random % (n - i);
//        cout << "nextPosition = " << nextPos << endl;
        arr[i] = arr[nextPos]; // swap
        arr[nextPos] = tmp;
    }
        //printArray(arr, n);
/*    bool chck = check(arr, n);
    if(chck == false)
        cout << "FALSE" << endl;
    else
        cout << "TRUE" << endl; */
}

void swapString(string arr[], int pos1, int pos2) {
    string tmp = arr[pos1];
    arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
    arr[pos2] = tmp;
    return;
}

void shuffleString(string strs[], int len) {
    int valArr[len];
    shufflePos(len, valArr);
    string to[len];
    // copying values into another array
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        to[i] = strs[valArr[i]];
    }
    // copying to[] into strs[]
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        strs[i] = to[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    string colorTheme[8][8] = {
        {"blue", "blue", "green", "green", "violet", "violet", "teal", "teal"},
        {"beige", "beige", "red", "red", "indigo", "indigo", "pink", "pink"},
        {"cyan", "cyan", "yellow", "yellow", "orange", "orange", "azure", "azure"},
        {"purple", "purple", "lime", "lime", "tangerine", "tangerine", "fuschia", "fuschia"},
        {"brown", "brown", "gray", "gray", "black", "black", "white", "white"},
        {"olive", "olive", "crimson", "crimson", "silver", "silver", "gold", "gold"},
        {"maroon", "maroon", "coral", "coral", "plum", "plum", "ivory", "ivory"},
        {"aqua", "aqua", "jade", "jade", "amber", "amber", "ruby", "ruby"}
    };
    cout << "What size of array do you want?" << endl;
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    int n = i * i; // length of 1D array
    string darr[n]; // 1D array
    for(int r = 0; r < i; r++) { // fill values of 1D array // rows
        for(int c = 0; c < i; c++) { // columns
            darr[(i * r + c)] = colorTheme[c][r];
        }
    }
    cout << 1 << endl;
    shuffleString(darr, n);
    cout << 2 << endl;
    // convert 1D array back into 2D array
    for(int r = 0; r < i; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
            colorTheme[c][r] = darr[(i * r) + c];
        }
    }
    for(int r = 0; r < i; r++) { // rows
        for(int c = 0; c < i; c++) { // columns
            cout << ": " << colorTheme[c][r] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You use variable-length arrays a lot. Note that in C++, they are a *non-standard extension* implemented by some compilers, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) and answers. You can use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk ah, I didn't realize that. I don't know how to use vector, so I simply used a variable-length array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't shuffle const array, but you can do it by changing it, I will post an example of shuffling a 2d array, you can refer that if you want to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    // the hard, inefficient way
    {
        enum { N = 7, M = 13 } ;
        char dest[N][M] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" } ;

        std::srand( std::time(nullptr) ) ;

        for( int i = N-1 ; i > 0 ; --i ) // fisher yates shuffle
        {
            const int pos = std::rand() % (i+1) ;
            char temp[M] ;
            std::strcpy( temp, dest[pos] ) ;
            std::strcpy( dest[pos], dest[i] ) ;
            std::strcpy( dest[i], temp ) ;
        }

        for( const char* cstr : dest ) std::cout << cstr << ' ' ;
        std::cout << '\n' ;
    }

    // the simple, efficient way
    {
        enum { N = 7 } ;
        std::string dest[N] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" } ;

        std::srand( std::time(nullptr) ) ; // if it has not already been done

        std::random_shuffle( std::begin(dest), std::end(dest) ) ;

        for( const std::string& str : dest ) std::cout << str << ' ' ;
        std::cout << '\n' ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using an `enum` is meaningful in C, to enforce that `M` and `N` are [integer constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) and that therefore a [variable-length array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) is not created. However, in C++, it is sufficient to simply write `const int N = 7, M = 13;` instead of `enum { N = 7, M = 13 } ;`.

Comment: Fyi, `std::random_shuffle` was deprecated in C++14, removed outright in C++17.  Use a decently clothed RNG or PRNG and `std::shuffle` instead. This also doesn't answer the question of shuffling only a partition of an array of arrays, *both* on the column *and* row axis.